# Having issues running Nodejs and React side with IIS running HTTPS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, https

I am having issues with running NodeJS as a backend for a React application (website) when utilizing HTTPS. The NodeJS runs on port 3001 waiting for requests. When React is running on IIS on HTTP and queries NodeJS (http://localhost:3001) everything is fine. However if I deploy SSL on the React application then the communication between React and NodeJS fails. I believe it is the security restriction of HTTPS and HTTP interacting.

The question then is, how do I run node on port 3001 but on HTTPS to deal with HTTPS origin requests?

I have looked at Reverse Proxy (https://dev.to/petereysermans/hosting-a-node-js-application-on-windows-with-iis-as-reverse-proxy-397b), looked at IISnode which doesn't seem to be supported anymore and read up on running NodeJS on HTTPS (which doesn't seem to be a viable solution).

Looking for any guidance and direction.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, typical that 10 minutes after you ask, you figure it out.

This is how I resolved the issue and someone more knowledgeable might correct me.

1. On IIS you have your HTTPS React website
2. Create a second Website on IIS (that also has SSL installed so can be accessed through Https).
3. On this second website you install the reverse proxy solution  (https://dev.to/petereysermans/hosting-a-node-js-application-on-windows-with-iis-as-reverse-proxy-397b) and route the requests to port 3001 on NodeJS application.

Effectively this means that the React application running on Https can now call NodeJS on Https (e.g. https://mynode.mysite.com) and the reverse proxy forwards the request to the NodeJS application on port 3001 (or the port that you are running NodeJs).

If I am wrong (this worked for me) or have gone the long route, please feel free to correct.

Thank you.